# Java : How to sort an array of floats in reverse order?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, floating-point

I use the following lines to sort an array of floats in reverse order, but I got an error message, what's wrong ?

```
float sortedData[]=new float[100];
  ...
Arrays.sort(sortedData,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Error : cannot find symbol

symbol  : method sort(float[],java.util.Comparator)
location: class java.util.Arrays
        Arrays.sort(sortedData,Collections.reverseOrder());

=========================================================================

I was confused because in Jdk1.6 api, I saw this  : [ Arrays ] public static void sort(**float**[] a), it doesn't say : public static void sort(**Float**[] a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That specific [method](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[],%20java.util.Comparator)), takes an array of type Object. The type float does not extend the Object class, but [Float](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) does.

```
Float sortedData[]=new Float[100];
...
Arrays.sort(sortedData,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: If you're using `float`s, you probably have a performance reason for doing so.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin, hardly in the year 2009? Only if you juggle A LOT of floats, and I do mean a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a `Arrays.sort(float[])` and then writing a method `reverse(float[])` (you may or may not want to shift the NaNs around).

Answer (score 2):

there is no `Arrays.sort(float[], Comparator)` method; however you can use or `Arrays.asList()` or just use a boxed Float[] array:

```
Float[] sortedData = new Float[100];
...
Arrays.sort(sortedData, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

In order to box a primitive array you can use the following code:

```
public static Float[] floatArray(float... components) {
    return toBoxedArray(Float.class, components);
}

private static <T> T[] toBoxedArray(Class<T> boxClass, Object components) {
    final int length = Array.getLength(components);
    Object res = Array.newInstance(boxClass, length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Array.set(res, i, Array.get(components, i));
    }

    return (T[]) res;
}
```

or include something like [commons lang in your project and use ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html)

Comment: `Arrays.asList` on `float[]` ain't gonna work (as you expect)!

Comment: (And I really wouldn't go for reflection.)

Comment: (Also doesn't to type checking for zero-length arrays.)

Comment: feel free to change the code; this is only a sample, for "real" needs use ArraysUtils from common lang

Comment: -1 for relying on boxing and reflection. It's much easier and better performant to just sort the array normally and then reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler isn't lying to you.  There isn't a method in Arrays called "sort" that takes an array of float and a Comparator.  There is, however, a method called "sort" which takes an array of Objects and a Comparator.  Perhaps if you converted your array to an array of Float before you called sort?

Think of it as a defect in Java's autoboxing if you will, that it can't autobox an array of primitives into an array of the equivalent Objects.

Answer (score 1):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) has a method [`Floats.asList()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Floats.html#asList%float...%29) for creating a `List<Float>` backed by a `float[]` array. You can use this with Collections.sort to apply the Comparator to the underlying array.

```
List<Float> floatList = Floats.asList(arr);
Collections.sort(floatList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Note that the list is a live view backed by the actual array, so it should be pretty efficient.

Comment: Floats.asList() links gives 404. May be you can use https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/Floats.java

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained why.  Can you sort it first and then reverse it?

Answer (score 0):

The same, using autoboxing in the for-loop:

```
double[] dbArray = {2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
Double[] dBArray = new Double[dbArray.length];
int i = 0;

for(Double db : dbArray){
    dBArray[i] = db; i++;
}
Arrays.sort(dBArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you can make use of Steam APIs like below -

(There is no FloatStream and direct mapToFloat method but you can always use double)

```
float[] unsorted = new float[100];
....
List<Double> sorted = IntStream.range(0, unsorted.length).mapToDouble(i->unsorted[i]).boxed().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1. Code using boxed method to converting primitive to object type.
2. Collections.reverseOrder() aids to the sorting in reverse order.
3. At last collecting it to list, here you can use other types as well.