# Sorting int array in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort arrays of primitive types in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215271/sort-arrays-of-primitive-types-in-descending-order)
>   [Java : How to sort an array of floats in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354326/java-how-to-sort-an-array-of-floats-in-reverse-order)
>   [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

The following code will sort the array in *ascending* order :

```
int a[] = {30,7,9,20};
Arrays.sort(a);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

I need to sort it in *descending* order. How do I use Comparator to do this?

Please help.

Comment: I just created [a library for sorting primitive arrays with a custom comparator](https://github.com/mintern-java/primitive#java-primitive). The first "sample usage" is sorting an `int[]` in descending order.

Comment: Just traverse the array in a descending order after sort.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For primitive array types, you would have to write a reverse sort algorithm:

Alternatively, you can convert your `int[]` to `Integer[]` and write a comparator:

```
public class IntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
}
```

or use `Collections.reverseOrder()` since it only works on non-primitive array types.

and finally,

```
Integer[] a2 = convertPrimitiveArrayToBoxableTypeArray(a1);
Arrays.sort(a2, new IntegerComparator()); // OR
// Arrays.sort(a2, Collections.reverseOrder());

//Unbox the array to primitive type
a1 = convertBoxableTypeArrayToPrimitiveTypeArray(a2);
```

Comment: error in convertPrimitiveArrayToBoxableTypeArray(a1)

Comment: @android, that method **never** exists, it's an example I created to do the conversion from `int[]` to `Integer[]`.

Comment: If i convert from int to Integer,then I can use Collections.reverseOrder but i have to conver again to int.Is this efficient?I think its better just to reverse the array after Aarrays.sort() then two conversion

Comment: @android, `Arrays.sort()` doesn't provide a facility to use a `Comparator` on the primitive array types, hence why the 2 conversion.

Answer (score 8):

If it's not a big/long array just mirror it:

```
for( int i = 0; i < arr.length/2; ++i ) 
{ 
  temp = arr[i]; 
  arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1]; 
  arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp; 
}
```

Comment: Yes.I know that.Actually i want to know is there a way to use Comparator,

Comment: Not on primitives. Comparator has to be implemented because it's an interface.

Comment: If you're going to do a foreach with a mirror, I think a negative iterator with (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) would be much simpler.

Answer (score 7):

```
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    };

    // option 1
    Integer[] array = new Integer[] { 1, 24, 4, 4, 345 };
    Arrays.sort(array, comparator);

    // option 2
    int[] array2 = new int[] { 1, 24, 4, 4, 345 };
    List<Integer>list = Ints.asList(array2);
    Collections.sort(list, comparator);
    array2 = Ints.toArray(list);
```

Comment: It seems the `Ints` class is in external google lib, `com.google.common.primitives.Ints`.

Answer (score 6):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) has a method [`Ints.asList()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29) for creating a `List<Integer>` backed by an `int[]` array. You can use this with Collections.sort to apply the Comparator to the underlying array.

```
List<Integer> integersList = Ints.asList(arr);
Collections.sort(integersList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Note that the latter is a live list backed by the actual array, so it should be pretty efficient.

Comment: Yes.I know that.Actually i want to know is there a way to use Comparator.

Comment: @android, no Comparator works on Objects, not primitives.

Comment: My eclipse showing error on ArrayUtils

Comment: @android forget ArrayUtils, use Guava