# Sorting an array in descending order?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, assign

I have looked at comparators and algorithms but I cannot make much sense of them. The comparator thing from java.util.Collections. 
So I chose to use this:

```
//return an array in descending order, using set algorithm
    public int[] descendSort()
    {
       int[] tempArray = new int[temps.length];

       for (int i = temps.length-1; i <= 0; --i)  
       {
            tempArray[i] = temps[i];
       }

    return tempArray;
    }
```

my created array in my client is this:

```
int[] temps1 = new int[]{45, 76, 12, 102, 107, 65, 43, 67, 81, 14};
```

My output ended up like this:.

```
The temperatures in descending order is:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

WHY????

Comment: Here you can see how to use the Comparator interface:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414299/sorting-int-array-in-descending-order

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I made a method where it sorted the array before hand, so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The condition `i <= 0` will never be met.

Also, `tempArray[i] = temps[i];` will just copy the array *as is*.

Either do:

```
   for (int i = temps.length-1; i >= 0; --i)  
   {
        tempArray[temps.length-1-i] = temps[i];
   }
```

or simply

```
   for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; ++i)  
   {
        tempArray[temps.length-1-i] = temps[i];
   }
```

Comment: I got an array out of bounds exception

Comment: tempArray[temps.length-i] to tempArray[temps.length-1-i]

Answer (score 1):

One-liner (doesn't work on primitives):

```
Integer[] temps1 = new Integer[] { 45, 76, 12, 102, 107, 65, 43, 67, 81, 14 };

Arrays.sort(temps1, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you sorting anything,you are just copying from one array to another. Here is a sorting code using a selection sort.
           public int [] descsort(){
            for(int i=0,imax)//if there is a bigger element,keep track of it
                 int index=j;

```
       int temp=temps[max];
       temps[max]=temps[index];

       temps[index]=temp;

     }
        return temps;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting Integer array in descending order can be done in this way:

Comparator comparator = new Comparator() {

```
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    };
    Integer[] array = new Integer[] { 9,1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0 };
    Arrays.sort(array, comparator);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```