# Sort int array in descending order using java 8 features (stream, lambda, etc)

Tags: java, java-8

Surprisingly, it seems there was no simple, one-liner kind of solution in java to sort int array in descending order before java 8. For example, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414299/sorting-int-array-in-descending-order). Now that we have java 8, is there an elegant, simple, one-liner way using java 8 features, such as stream and lambda expression, to sort an int array in descending order?

**Edit**
I am interested in a solution for `int[]`, not `Integer[]`.

**Edit**
I am interested in a solution that only uses JAVA SE library.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Sort arrays of primitive types in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215271/sort-arrays-of-primitive-types-in-descending-order)

Comment: You can always use `Arrays.sort()` and then iterate the array in reverse order...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With guava you could simply write

```
Ints.asList(a).sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

It may be not so efficient since it requires boxing int to Integer, but it is elegant one-liner.

You can also write something like

```
int[] sorted = IntStream.of(a)
        .boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .mapToInt(i -> i)
        .toArray();
```

but this also suffers from boxing and it needs to create new array.

Anyway I doubt you will find nice solution in standard Java free of boxing since `Comparator<T>` can accept only objects. For now best way would be using `Arrays.sort` and reverse its order manually.

Comment: In my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library there's a [shortcut](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#reverseSorted--) for this: `IntStreamEx.of(a).reverseSorted().toArray()` (which does the same boxing/unboxing internally). In JDK there's no ready algorithm to sort primitive array with custom comparator, so it's not possible to do this without intermediate boxing (or some third-party library which implements such primitive sorting).

Answer (score 5):

```
int[] arr = ...;
Arrays.sort(arr);
int[] reversed = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                          .map(i -> arr[arr.length-i-1])
                          .toArray();
```

is probably the closest you could do if you don't want to box the `int` into its respective wrapper class for each value in the array.

If you suffer from performances by doing the sort once (`O(nlogn)`) and the reverse operation after (`O(n)`), you might want to look into `Arrays.parallelSort` and parallelize the `IntStream`.

Comment: or `IntStream.range(0, arr.length/2).forEach(i -> {int tmp = arr[i]; arr[i] = arr[arr.length-i-1]; arr[arr.length-i-1] = tmp;});` if you want to reverse in place in `arr` directly.