# java comparator for arrays sort

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

My code is shown below:

```
public class Solution {
    public void nextPermutation(int[] nums) {
        int k = 0;
        for(int i = nums.length -1; i> 0 ;i--){
            if(nums[i-1] < nums[i]){
                k = i-1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( k == 0) {Arrays.sort(nums); return;}
        int tmp = nums[k];
        nums[k] = nums[nums.length - 1];
        nums[nums.length-1] = tmp;
        Arrays.sort(nums,k+1,nums.length,new Comparator<Integer>(){
            public int compare(Integer a, Integer b){
                return b - a;
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

I want to sort the array in decreasing order by using comparator, but it always shows

> Line 14: error: no suitable method found for sort(int[],int,int,
>   anonymous Comparator)

Can anyone point out where is the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @cricket_007 ...How is this a duplicate? This question asks about a compiler error, that one asks how to speed up an algorithm, and the answers to both are most definitely not the same.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes The error is because primitives are attempted to be sorted, yes?

Comment: @cricket_007 That's not the criteria for duplicate. Look at the answers of the question you linked -- do they answer the question directly? Sure, you could get _an_ answer, but the key problem -- that `int` and `Integer` aren't the same type, and `int`s can't be used in generic methods at all -- isn't addressed

Comment: @QPaysTaxes And what about this one? Which also got flagged to that other post. [Sort int array in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414299/sorting-int-array-in-descending-order)

Comment: @cricket_007 That one is explicitly asking "How do I sort integers?". This one is asking "I have code that is supposed to perform some task, but I'm getting a compiler error. Why?" The fact that the task _happens_ to be sorting integers doesn't mean a thing. Again, look at the answers of your proposed duplicate. Do they answer the question asked -- namely, "Where is the problem?" No. They give a(n alternate) solution for the task at hand, which is useful, but not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method that takes a *primitive* array like `int[] nums` and sorts it in descending order. There are some that take an array of Objects, like [`sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) - but primitives are not `Objects`<sup>1</sup>.

The most straightforward method is likely to simply `sort(int[] input)` your array in ascending order, then [reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java) the resulting array. The sort is likely to take significantly longer than the reverse, so this method should perform well. Alternately, you may be able to modify the consuming code so that it deals with the array in ascending order, or you could wrap the array in a `List` and then use a reversed view.

There are [lots of other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215271/sort-arrays-of-primitive-types-in-descending-order) as well.

---

<sup>1</sup> You could, in principle, convert your `int[]` into an `Integer[]`, by boxing each underlying `int` element, but you would pay a large performance penalty and a huge memory (increasing the memory used by about 10x) and garbage penalty to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is of type `int` and Comparator generic type is `Integer`. Change your array type to Integer and everything will be fine, like this:

`public void nextPermutation(Integer[] nums) {...`

Comment: You would pay a terrible performance and memory penalty by converting your entire array to boxed `Integer` objects just to use this method!

Comment: That's definitely true, put edit on my post and I will add it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "put edit"...

Answer (score 0):

Your `nums` array must be of type `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Arrays.sort` overload that takes a `Comparator` can only work on arrays of Objects; `int` isn't a valid substitution for a generic type argument.

So,

```
Integer[] intObjs = ...;
int[] intPrimitives = ...;
Arrays.sort(intObjs, start, end, someComparator); //OK
Arrays.sort(intPrimitives, start, end, someComparator); //fails
```

For what you want to work, there'd have to be an Arrays.sort overload declared to take an `int[]` - but that'd be a costly sort, since it'd basically require boxing the `int`s for each comparison.