# Data Type to store 1.0.0.0

Tags: java, android, types

My requirement is to store the below values.
for example

```
someDataType val1 = 1.0.0.0;
someDatatype val2 = 1.0.0.1;
someDatatype val3 = 2.0.0.0;
```

etc.

we can't use

```
double d = 1.4;
float f = 0.0f;
```

How can i compare this values to know which is the smallest number and which is the largest one?

To achieve this, what data type I can use?
It seems a silly question, but I am really not getting how to proceed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java : How to sort an array of floats in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354326/java-how-to-sort-an-array-of-floats-in-reverse-order)

Comment: @AbdulWaheed we cant store 1.0.0.0 as a float data type, only we can store 1.0, 1.023, 3.143 like this

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve .. as some sort of versionCode simple int would do and to display just add the dots or make it a string and write your own compare method .. more really depends on what it is later used for

Comment: @Tobi can i know what ur supposed to tell

Comment: @Tobi i want to know which value is greater either 1.0.0.0 or 1.0.0.2

Comment: You can only use **String** for such a value.

Comment: @NoiseGenerator everyone know that we can use string, but comparison is not possible, here rises the problem

Comment: @Nitesh then you will need to build a custom data type that stores each set of integers as integers. Then you can create a compare function. (I'm assuming those are IP addresses).

Comment: I feel like some people don't understand the question or simple marks down votes. i searched a lot and then only i post a question here

Comment: simple .. both string are separated by the dots as substring (can be casted as int and compared to the respective other substring)

Comment: @Nitesh If you already knew that string is **the only** data type you can use, then why did you ask?

Comment: @Sheldon those are version numbers not a ip address, anyway i will try ur suggestion

Comment: @NoiseGenerator if you can tell how to compare and know which value is greater, your suggestion of storing into string is more valuable

Comment: I added an answer which should put you on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

String is the only datatype you can use for a value such as 1.2.3.4.

An easy way to compare the nth element with an integer is that you can use string.split() and get an array of strings. Each element can be then parsed to an integer.

I.e.:

```
String value = "1.2.3.4";
String[] elements = value.split("\\."); // escape "."
if (Integer.parseInt(elements[1]) == 2) // compare to an integer
{
    // which is true in this case: elements[1] is "2"
}
```

Comment: I will try to implement your idea for my requirement

Comment: It should be a piece of cake... ;)